# Laravel Eloquent: How to automatically fetch relations when serializing through toArray/toJson

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I figures this works for automatically fetching `user` and `replies` when I am serializing my object to JSON, but is overriding `toArray` really the proper way of doing this?

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('parent_post_id', 'user_id', 'subject', 'body');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $this->load('user', 'replies');
        return parent::toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Instead of overriding `toArray()` to load user and replies, use `$with`.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('parent_post_id', 'user_id', 'subject', 'body');

    protected $with = array('user', 'replies');


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_post_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Also, you should be using `toArray()` in your controllers, not your models, like so:

```
Post::find($id)->toArray();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant. I expected there to be a more clever way.
I am utilizing the Route::model method to automatically fetch and pass the proper model to my controller. It is an AJAX call requesting JSON, so Laravel automatically handles the toJson call when I return the model in my controller method :-) http://pastebin.com/5MMwiXS2

Comment: This was super helpful to me -- thanks!  Do you happen to know if `$with` is documented anywhere?  I couldn't find it in the Laravel docs, but it does seem to do the trick.

Comment: It's only [in the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L68), it seems.

Comment: This solution will load the relationship at all times. Not only when serializing. Be aware of the potential overhead for other use cases.

Comment: I have seen several examples where an entity is loaded using find, what about a collection, say using get or paginate!

Answer (score 8):

I must submit a new answer since I'm a SO pleb. A more proper way to accomplish this for those finding this on Google like I did would be to avoid using `protected $with` if you don't have to and instead move that `with()` call to your retrieval.

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('parent_post_id', 'user_id', 'subject', 'body');


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_post_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

And then you could modify the Post call to pre-load as needed:

```
Post::with('user','replies')->find($id)->toArray();
```

This way, you won't be including un-needed data every time you grab a record, if you don't need it.

Comment: This does not answer the question to automatically fetch when serializing.

Comment: The above answer, specifically `Post::with('user','replies')->find($id)->toArray();` will load a post with the relationships without having to override toArray as was asked. Moreover, this is simply a revision on the accepted answer posted by Jake to make it much more efficient so you don't have to load user and replies every time a post is instantiated.